# unable to count numbers of char type

Tags: c++, function, counter

I'm trying to do a certain counter for my assignment but I tried many methods but i still can't figure them out.

My program allows users to find out the type of triangle based on their input.

So i do have 2 main functions to determine the shape of the triangle and to display the counter.

> 1. char shapeTriangle(int, int, int); //determine shape of triangle i.e isosceles ('I'), equilateral ('E')
> 2. int summaryDisplay(char); // display counter

In my `shapeTriangle` function, i have a simple if else statement that returns the type based on the user input

```
char shapeTriangle(int x, int y, int z)
{

char type;

if (x == y && y == z && x == z)

type = 'E';

else if (x == y || y == z || x == z)

type = 'I';
    
return type;
}
```

Over at my `main function`, i have loop that allows user to input till one of the value is a 0.

In `summaryDisplay`, i'm trying to count the number of times a certain triangle is determined

```
int finalSum(char type)

int eCount = 0,  iCount = 0;

if (type == 'E')

eCount++;

if (type == 'I')

iCount++;
        
cout << "Equilateral" << eCount;
cout << "Isosceles" << iCount;

}
```

I managed to obtain an output however, the counter returns me some weird values like `540934` or `3453` etc etc which i can't really figure them out.

This is how i attempt to call my function in my `int main`

```
int main()

{

int x, y, z;  

do{

cout << "Enter 3 intgers : ";
cin >> x >> y >> z;

//some display output codes

}while ( x != 0 && y != 0 && z != 0); 

finalSum(shapeTriangle(x, y, z));

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

***EDIT 1 :*** I tried initializing but however, it returns me 0 for all different types.

Comment: if neither your condition is false, you return uninitialized `type`.

Comment: `eCount`, `iCount` are not initialized either.

Comment: i tried initializing as 0 but it seems to still return me 0 counters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize your counters with Zero which will behave as your counter starting value. Like this:

```
int eCount = 0, iCount = 0;
```

Also, what would you like `type` to be if none of your conditions met? Because if you did not initialize `type` and none of your conditions met (`if (x == y && y == z && x == z)` and `if (x == y || y == z || x == z)`) then later both of your counters will stay 0.

Comment: i cut short my codes. To be detailed, i do have 4 different types that is `equilateral`, `scalene`, `isosceles`, and `notatriangle`. So once if none of the condition is met, the counter will be added to the `notatriangle` type. Unfortunately, all the return counter are still 0 even though my `int main` displays and read different type of triangle

Comment: Then initialize your `type` as `N` like this: `char type = 'N';` if you want that to be your default value..

Comment: i dont have any default values. I have loop that cancels any input once the input does not matches any of the 4 different types.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize your variables.

Answer (score 0):

It lookes like you've declared `eCount` and `iCount` inside the scope of `finalSum()`. This means that their values, if not initialized, will be garbage from previous activity on the stack, which is what you're seeing. <del>Try declaring them globally, to preserve their values across function calls</del>.

You should make sure that your counting variables are properly declared and initialized before they are incremented, otherwise you are wading into undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm trying to "preserve" all counter fcuntions in that `displaySummary` function. That is why i declared it locally instead of globally. but i don't get why does it return me garbage info even though i'm just trying to extract out the value from the counter within the function.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan Uninitialized variables have Undefined Behavior with respect to the value they receive; usually, they receive garbage from the memory that existed on the stack before the function was placed on the stack. Make sure you initialize it like `char type = 'u';` before you do anything else with it.

Comment: @Rakete1111 easy on the beginner. Also, as the code is written, `eCount` and `iCount` **are never initialized** which is your biggest concern here, as well as with `type`.

Comment: *Please* don't recommend global variables.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with using global variables.

Comment: @FirstStep Yes, there absolutely is.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Could you please tell me why? I have been programming maybe for 1 year by now and I always use global variables. All applications work just fine, with a clean and understandable code.. so I would like to hear from an experienced programmer

Comment: Global variables generally aren't friendly to large-scale applications and maintainability. Using global variables instead of return values can make things nigh-impossible to debug, and that's certainly something to avoid. Otherwise, global variables lead to clutter if they're not needed and if they're not restricted to the classes/namespaces where they matter.

Comment: @FirstStep Because they make your program utterly unpredictable. The only reason your programs nevertheless work is because they’re small. Here, some literature: [Action at a distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance_(computer_programming)), [“Global variables are bad”](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad), [“Why is global state so evil?”](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/148108/2366). — Really, don’t underestimate how bad this is: [it destroys programs](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/4tlr2u/john_carmack_on_inlined_code/d5iqxio).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a default value for `type`. What if all three input values are different? No values are assigned to `type` in your `if` statements and this is not initialised.

Try to put a default value like `'U'` for unknown...

Comment: as mentioned above, i do have a default values that i did not input into the question in order to cut short my codes. I have 4 different type which is `equilateral`, `scalene`, `isosceles`, and `notatriangle`. So there will definitely be something initialization to the `type`. Unfortunately, it still returns me 0 for all counters.